# Regex match tab or nothing

Tags: regex, tabs

Please see this [expression](https://regex101.com/r/DwE9QR/9)
I am looking for the expression to match the first line too.
The number of tabs in each line, may be 4 or less, so this is unknown
The first line should return:

```
Order\t2187405\tDvbzVvmLL\t\t\t481
```

after the substitution

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex, which looks for a group of non-tab characters, followed by up to 4 optional groups of tab followed by some number (possibly 0) of non-tab characters:

```
^([^\t]*)(?:\t([^\t]*))?(?:\t([^\t]*))?(?:\t([^\t]*))?(?:\t([^\t]*))?$
```

Substitute with (I'm presuming you want the `481` that was in your demo):

```
$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t481
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AAAiH1/3)

Comment: That does it. Thank you so much.